# 'javac' is not recognized

Tags: java, environment-variables, javac

I have added Path variable `'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin'` in Environment Variables, but it still gives me this error: `'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` when I try to run `javac mycode.java`. I am going insane, please help. Thanks.

Comment: do `echo %PATH%` and show us the output

Comment: This is much better question than the original one, but I'm still wondering why you had to ask a new question for the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close the command prompt window and open it again so that the new environment variables take effect.

Comment: Of course this step was mentioned in the instructions I linked to the original question. Wonder if he ever read them...

Comment: Now I tried to change .java file's directory and it works. But it gives me an error: `C:\Users\Tomas>javac hello.java
hello.java:1: class my_first is public, should be declared in a file named my_fi
rst.java
public class my_first`

Comment: Rename your .java file to my_first.java and try compiling again. The source code file must have the same name of your class, in this case, my_first.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong. The name of the file must match the name of the class. Rename hello.java to my_first.java and it should work.